# Is it possible for Swagger to get the authorization token from URL query string?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

In a .NET Core project, I add a security definition (code at the bottom), which adds an Authorize button to the page and the user can enter the api key - everything works fine.

Is it possible to specify the api key in the URL so that Swagger automatically uses that instead of having to enter it?  Like `/swagger/index.html?authorization=0123456789` or something to that effect.

Existing code:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  ...
  c.AddSecurityDefinition("api key", new ApiKeyScheme() {
      Description = "Authorization query string expects API key",
      In = "query",
      Name = "authorization",
      Type = "apiKey"
  });

  var requirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
      { "api key", new List<string>().AsEnumerable() }
  };
  c.AddSecurityRequirement(requirements);
});
```

Seems like the URL with `authorization` parameter should work, but it doesn't.

P.S. Using Swashbuckle 4.0.x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible, but you will have to override Swagger-UI's index page so you can plug your custom handler into `onComplete` callback.

1. Grab latest index.html from [Swashbuckle's source repo](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/index.html) (ideally, get the matching version)
2. Tweak `configObject` to add an `OnComplete` callback handler so it will call [`preauthorizeApiKey`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md) when the UI is ready
3. Override `IndexStream` in `UserSwaggerUI` extension method to serve the custom html

I ended up having the following setup (some bits are omitted for brevity):

### wwwroot/swashbuckle.html

```
<!-- your standard HTML here, nothing special -->
<script>
    // some boilerplate initialisation
    // Begin Swagger UI call region
    configObject.onComplete = () => {

        // get the authorization portion of the query string
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        if (urlParams.has('authorization')) {
            var apikey = urlParams.get('authorization');

            // this is the important bit, see documentation
            ui.preauthorizeApiKey('api key', apikey );// key name must match the one you defined in AddSecurityDefinition method in Startup.cs
       }
    }
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle(configObject);
    window.ui = ui        
}
</script>
```

### Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        .........
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "You api title", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("api key", new ApiKeyScheme() // key name must match the one you supply to preauthorizeApiKey call in JS
            {
                Description = "Authorization query string expects API key",
                In = "query",
                Name = "authorization",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });

            var requirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
                { "api key", new List<string>().AsEnumerable() }
            };
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(requirements);
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.IndexStream = () => File.OpenRead("wwwroot/swashbuckle.html"); // this is the important bit. see documentation https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1"); // very standard Swashbuckle init
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

After you've done all that, calling the standard swagger URL with ?authorization=1234567890 should automatically authorize the page.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick.  I also edited your solution to fetch the url parameter.